# The execution process of preprocessing commands in C++

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

Recently I am learning some advanced programming skills in metaprogramming, and I have met some kind of problem understanding the execution of preprocessing commands in C++. Originnal I assumed preprocessing commands are executed in the order they are in C++ codes. However, given the following code, it does not produce expected result.

```
#include <cstdio>

void a() {
    printf("a\n");
}

void b() {
    printf("b\n");
}

void c() {
    printf("c\n");
}

int main() {

#define a b
#define c a

    a(); // 1. a() -> b()

    b();

    c(); // 2. c() -> a()

#undef c
#undef a

    return 0;
}

/*
if #define is executed in order, then expect
b
b
a

however get
b
b
b
*/
```

I thought it would first execute the substitution of

```
#define a b
```

to produce

```
int main() {
    b();

    b();

    c();

    return 0;

}
```

then execute

```
#define c a
```

to produce

```
int main() {
    b();

    b();

    a();

    return 0;

}
```

However, when I compile this code and run it in terminal, I get

```
b
b
b
```

Therefore, I wonder exactly how to understand the execution process of #define and also other preprocessing commands.

Thanks.

Comment: You have a pair of replacements so the first case is actually `c() -> a() -> b()`. Also in general I would strongly avoid macros, in most cases they harm readability and there are more idiomatic ways to accomplish their various uses.

Comment: The preprocessor scans the source only once, applying all suitable macros. It doesn't do a separate scan per macro. Further, the order the macros were created in doesn't matter, what matters is what macros exist at any given line.

Comment: meta programming is usually not done through macros (which are not recommended to be used in C++), but through class and function templates. I think all your code does at the moment is making things more confusing then they should be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file is scanned once and the c preprocessor (CPP) has a state it maintains through lines. At any line, the order in which the currently existing macros were defined does not matter:

```
#define A B // CPP notes down A->B
#define C A // CPP notes down C->A

A // Expands to B
B // Stays B
C // Expands to A, which again expands to B

#undef A // CPP removes the entry for A
#define A D // CPP notes down A->D

A // Expands to D
B // Stays B
C // Expands to A, which again expands to D
```

[See the expansion online](https://godbolt.org/z/r1zY1Wrbf)

Answer (score 3):

The preprocessor does execute in order. Specifically, it executes line-by-line. Some of the lines are preprocessor directives (such as `#define`); others are not. When the preprocessor processes a `#define` directive, it does so by adding that definition to its set of macro definitions. When the preprocessor processes a regular line of code, it does so by (among other things) looking for tokens which match macro definitions and substituting them with the replacement. If the replacement itself includes macro names, those macros are again replaced.

So when it encounters `c();`, it first uses the macro definition of `c` to produce `a();`. Then it uses the macro definition of `a` to produce `b();`. That contains no macro names to substitute, so it's done.

Note that the order of `#define` statements relative to *each other* is unimportant. `#define` simply puts entries in the macro table. They have no effect until they're used in regular lines of code.